# Can't get the delete function to work it keeps telling me "object has no splice method"

Tags: javascript

Can't get the delete function to work it keeps telling me object has no splice method.

```
function del() { 
  var x = document.getElementById("display");  
  x.value.splice(x.value.length - 1,  1);
}


<input type="text"/><br /><button onclick="del()">delete</button>
```

Comment: put .split("") inbetween or use .substr

Comment: All the values from HTML are always strings, and string doesn't have splice method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `x` is an `HTMLInputElement` then `x.value` is a `string` and not an `Array`

The easiest way to remove the last character of a `string` is using the `substring` method

So you can do `x.substring(0, x.length-1)`